# "Error#2025 The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller." upon trying to removeChild();

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, runtime-error, removechild

I'm creating a simple iPhone game (but the class I'm in is requiring me to use Flash...), and I'm having a major issue as I'm trying to remove objects from the game.

The game is somewhat of a dynamic time-wasting bubblewrap game where there are infinite "refreshes" of the stage. Once the user pops all the bubbles, more randomly generate. (When the array is empty, call the `setup()` again.)

For now, I have one of each five different colored bubble graphics pulled from the library by code and placed on the stage randomly. However, I don't like the overlap, so I've given each bubble a small square hitspace so when they're placed randomly and overlap significantly they pop themselves. For some reason when I'm trying to remove the bubbles it gives me

> Error#2025 The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller.

I've tried adding stage to `addChild` and `removeChild`, but I get the same error.

```
import flash.events.*;
import flash.display.*;

var bubbles:Array = new Array();

var b:BlueBubble = new BlueBubble();
var b2:GreenBubble = new GreenBubble();
var b3:PinkBubble = new PinkBubble();
var b4:PurpleBubble = new PurpleBubble();
var b5:YellowBubble = new YellowBubble();

// values to be tweaked later
var bNum:uint = 1;
var maxSize:uint = 100;
var minSize:uint = 1;
var range:uint = maxSize - minSize;
var tooBig:uint = 100;

function init():void {
setup();
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEveryFrame);
}

function setup():void {
for (var i:uint=0; i<bNum; i++) {
    // blue
    b.width = Math.ceil(Math.random() * range) + minSize;
    b.height = b.width;
    b.x = Math.random()*(stage.stageWidth - b.width);
    b.y = Math.random()*(stage.stageHeight - b.height);
    bubbles.push(b);
    stage.addChild(b);
    // green
    b2.width = Math.ceil(Math.random() * range) + minSize;
    b2.height = b2.width;
    b2.x = Math.random()*(stage.stageWidth - b2.width);
    b2.y = Math.random()*(stage.stageHeight - b2.height);
    bubbles.push(b2);
    stage.addChild(b2);
    // pink
    b3.width = Math.ceil(Math.random() * range) + minSize;
    b3.height = b3.width;
    b3.x = Math.random()*(stage.stageWidth - b3.width);
    b3.y = Math.random()*(stage.stageHeight - b3.height);
    bubbles.push(b3);
    stage.addChild(b3);
    // purple
    b4.width = Math.ceil(Math.random() * range) + minSize;
    b4.height = b4.width;
    b4.x = Math.random()*(stage.stageWidth - b4.width);
    b4.y = Math.random()*(stage.stageHeight - b4.height);
    bubbles.push(b4);
    stage.addChild(b4);
    // yellow
    b5.width = Math.ceil(Math.random() * range) + minSize;
    b5.height = b5.width;
    b5.x = Math.random()*(stage.stageWidth - b5.width);
    b5.y = Math.random()*(stage.stageHeight - b5.height);
    bubbles.push(b5);
    stage.addChild(b5);

    //add event listeners for bubbles later

}
}
function onEveryFrame(e:Event) {
for (var i:uint=0; i<bubbles.length; i++) {

    bubbles[i].width++;
    bubbles[i].height++;

    if (bubbles[i].height >= tooBig && bubbles[i].width >= tooBig) {
        bubbles[i].height = tooBig;
        bubbles[i].width = tooBig;
    }

    // Blue hit testing
    if (b2.hitGreen.hitTestObject(b.hitBlue)) {
            removeChild(b);
    }
    if (b3.hitPink.hitTestObject(b.hitBlue)) {
            removeChild(b);
    }
    if (b4.hitPurple.hitTestObject(b.hitBlue)) {
            removeChild(b);
    }
    if (b5.hitYellow.hitTestObject(b.hitBlue)) {
            removeChild(b);
    }

    // Other hit testing...

}
}

init();
```

Answer (score 2):

You are adding `b`, `b2`, `b3`, etc to the `stage`, but removing them from whatever object is executing this code. Try changing

```
stage.addChild(b);
```

to

```
addChild(b);
```

Additionally, it is a good idea to check that an object is a child before removing it. Try changing

```
if (...)
    removeChild(b);
```

to

```
if (contains(b) && ...)
    removeChild(b);
```

Comment: Glad I could help. Please accept the answer to close the question.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to solve this is:

```
mc.parent.removeChild(mc);
```

Basically, the removeChild function needs to be called from whatever display object that your soon to be removed object is in.

Comment: Well, that kind of worked, swapped the previous error for "Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference." ...But nothing is null from what I understand, so why would it do that?